# How to relate PowerBuilder .srj contents to PowerGen .gen contents?

Tags: powerbuilder

In  PowerBuilder, to locally deploy the application, you can use the .srj file which has a whole lot of tickbox options, plus a list of packages to include. An example is this:.

```
/* myapp.srj */
HA$PBExportHeader$myapp.srj
EXE:c:\dev\core\myapp.exe,,0,1,1
CMP:0,0,0,2,0,0
COM:My Application
DES:My Application
CPY:2011
PRD:My App
PVS:2
PVN:4,0,0,0
FVS:2
FVN:4,0,0,0
PBD:C:\_p4\chk\branches\PB\app\myapp.pbl,,1
PBD:C:\_p4\chk\branches\PB\app\myapp2.pbl,,1
PBD:... and so on
```

However, you can use the fancy(tm) PowerGen, you can automate the process of building, using this funky kind of file:

```
/* myapp.gen */
$PowerGenVersion=12
$ProjectName="","powergen.log",0,""
$DefaultApplication=""
$DefaultLibrary=""
$ApplicationName="myapp",0,0,0,0,0,1257441159,1, 0
$ApplicationLibrary="app\myapp.PBL",0
$EXEPath=".\bin\myapp.exe","",1,0
$CodeSigning=
$ICOPath="myapp.ico"
$PBRPath=""
$PBDPath=".\bin",1,0
$SourceControl="","","","",0,0
$Library="app\myapp.pbl","myapp.pbr",0,0,0,"app\myapp.pbg"
$Library="app\myapp2.pbl","",0,2,0,"app\myapp2.pbg"
```

My issue is there is a problem where what I expect my settings to be in the .srj file are not being translated over to the .gen file.

Does anyone know of any documentation that describes how the settings in the .gen file relate to the .srj file?

I am specifically after the comparative settings for the .srj file line starting `CMP:` but a full documentation of the settings would be great :)

.

.

.

.

I've gone to the PowerGen on our system, and tried saving a copy of the gen file with and without my setting on, and it looks like it's this line:
`$EXEPath=".\bin\myapp.exe","",1,1`

`$EXEPath=".\bin\myapp.exe","",1,0` < New Visual Style Controls off
`$EXEPath=".\bin\myapp.exe","",1,1` < New Visual Style Controls on

Would still like some documentation though. I have no .chm file coming up though F1 on our install of PowerGen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a pretty robust PDF document installed into the Program Files directory where PowerGen is installed. However, looking at mine, I don't see the answers you're looking for. The other place to check is [E Crane's support forums](http://www.ecrane.com/ecraneforum/index.cfm); I've always found E Crane to have great support.

Good luck,

Terry.